# Seeking Stack Exchange site for asking about 3OXZ CAD file Format converting question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have one question about output files of dental scanner, the output file is in 3oxz format which we  need to  change it to stl format for some analyzing, SO where could I ask this question in stackexchange sites.

the question in engineering is here:

[How to convert *.3OXZ CAD files to *.STL in ***engineering.stackexchange.com***](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15657/how-to-convert-3oxz-cad-files-to-stl)

Is that the right place to ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

If that was not the right place to ask it they will let you know soon enough, and most likely will suggest where it may be more on-topic.

You only asked less than an hour ago so give that site some time to see and respond to your question.